# How can I specify the height in react project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

Happy Friday.

I've tried putting the following in options but none seem to make any change.

```
"height": "100%"
"height": "450px"
"height": "auth"
```

I prefer not to change in css. only react component.
How can I set the height?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the CodePen for your project?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height via css on .CodeMirror, auto will cause it to take the height of the contents.
It's documented here: https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#styling